# Active Directory VBScript Get Users shared mailbox list

Tags: vbscript, exchange-server

I have found a few scripts online but all are so confusing and about 10 pages long LOL...

what im after is to enter a userid and search AD and the result im after is something like:

Name: Pavle Stoj
Email: pavle.stoj@...

Shared Mailboxes Pavle has access too:

- mailbox 1
- mailbox 2
- mailbox 3

I can get Name and Email etc but when I get to the shared mailbox access I dont know commands to run to get them ?

Example of what I have so far which works fine for me..

```
' Check Exchange attributes for a 'user'
'
'
' -------------------------------------------------
' -------------------------------------------------

' Search box for userid
' ----------------------

strUsername = Inputbox ("UserID ?")
' -------------------------------------------------

' -------------------------------------------------
' Connect to AD and use the userid entered
' -------------------------------------------------

Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
strDomain = objRootDSE.Get("DefaultNamingContext")
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = 2
objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT distinguishedName FROM 'LDAP://" & strDomain & "' WHERE     objectCategory='User' AND samAccountName = '" & strUsername & "'"
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute


' -------------------------------------------------
' Quick Check the user exists in AD
' ----------------------------------

If Not objRecordSet.EOF Then
    strDistOU = objRecordSet.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
Else
   MsgBox("No Results for: " & strUsername)
   Wscript.Quit
End If

' -------------------------------------------------

Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDistOU)

strName = objUser.FullName

MsgBox strName
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out...

```
delegateList = objUser.Get("publicDelegatesBL")

 For Each Desc In delegateList

  Set objMailbox = GetObject("LDAP://" & desc)
  WScript.Echo " " & objMailbox.DisplayName

 Next
```